# How to distinguish class and delegate using Type API in C#

Tags: c#, class, reflection, delegates

[`Type.IsClass`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.isclass?view=netframework-4.8#System_Type_IsClass) property tells whether the type is a class or a delegate. How to distinguish between these two (class and delegate) using [`Type`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type?view=netframework-4.8) class API?

Comment: If you need to check on a specific instance, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5819975). If you need to check on a specific _type_, [see this answer instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5819935).

Comment: @PeterDuniho Why was the question closed? I specifically asks about Type class API. The suggested already existing question https://stackoverflow.com/q/5819907/639687 doesn't mention the key trick `.IsSubclassOf(typeof(System.Delegate)))` shown in an answer below. Suggested already existing answer deals with checking on an instance rather than a Type.

Comment: Please read my previous comment. The duplicate is simply one of many existing questions on SO that explain how to determine where a object's type lands within the type system, and I even provided a link in my comment to the answer that addresses your question _exactly_. For your edification, I've added several other questions which are also duplicates of this question.

Comment: This question is the more straight to the point and has the more explicit title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if type [is a subclass of](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.issubclassof?view=netframework-4.8) `System.Delegate`:

```
typeof(Foo).IsSubclassOf(typeof(System.Delegate)));
```